# String-to-float conversion

Tags: arduino, gps, xbee

I am transferring GPS values through an XBee using Arduino Uno. I have done this by using `long` and now I am trying to do it with float. The data is `11.235689, 76.365879`.

How can I do parsing and convert from string to float?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
char floatbuf[32]; 
coordinates.toCharArray(floatbuf, sizeof(floatbuf));
float f = atof(floatbuf);
```

You can see more [here](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/rtref/itof.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response, This is how I have converted from string to float

```
String data; // declare this before void setup

data=XBee.readStringUntil('\n');  //reads XBbee data to string
int commaIndex=data.indexOf(',');   
int secondcommaIndex=data.indexOf(',',commaIndex+1);
String data1=data.substring(0,commaIndex);
String data2=data.substring(commaIndex+1);

char charBuff[10];
data1.toCharArray(charBuff,10);
float input_lat= atof(charBuff);
Serial.print("input_lat: ");
Serial.println(input_lat,6);

char chaBuff[10];
data2.toCharArray(chaBuff,10);
float input_lng= atof(chaBuff);
Serial.print("input_lng: ");
Serial.println(input_lng,6);
```